# QML - Windows taskbar shows up when launching an application from an ApplicationWindow in fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, qml, fullscreen, taskbar

I am building a Qml ApplicationWindow and I want it to be in fullscreen and always on top (I use visibility: FullScreen and the Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint flag). It works, but when I launch background applications from the UI, the windows taskbar shows up and overlaps the UI.

I am running the application on Windows 7.

Any ideas on how to prevent the taskbar to show up ?

Thanks.